# How can i locate my background image

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

My custom css is in 
**resources > assets > sass > _custom.scss** 
and my images are stored in 
**storage > app > public > myimages.jpg**

> How can i access my background images to place in my css. TIA

Comment: What is your reason for putting the image in `storage` instead of `public`?

Comment: i actually link the storage to my public folder but the image didn't show up

Comment: Do you want to call the url in your blade file or your css file?

Comment: just accessing my css file

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below that you want to use the image as a background but you don't want the image to be accessible online, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

To use images in css, you need to create a folder here

> resources/assets/images

and then call in the css code

> ../images/img.png

Comment: i dont want to put the image in the resources btw because i dont want to access it by the internet